# Is this sentence,"I gave my dad a mobile phone last year. This is so that I can contact him whenever I want to." correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

A typical sentence with "so that" is:

> I gave my dad a mobile phone last year **so that** I can contact him whenever I want to.

But how about this version:

> I gave my dad a mobile phone last year. This is **so that** I can contact him whenever I want to.

The word "is" is a linking verb. So can the phrase "so that" be noun?

Comment: "is" can be followed by noun, adjective ("This is fat"), preposition ("This is on the table"), adverb, and other parts of speech. I don't really want to get into what part of speech "so that" is, because these things are endlessly debatable and a dictionary can probably tell you better than I, but you're wrong to think "is" must be followed by a noun. You'd get the same meaning with e.g. "This is in order for me to be able to contact him".

Comment: I think it's not strictly accurate to say *The phrase "so that" means "for the purpose of"*. It's really just the word ***so*** (a ***subordinating conjunction** to introduce clauses of result or decision*) that can have this meaning - following it with the relativizer ***that*** is *always* optional.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What if the sentence was "I bought him a phone **so** *I could call him*." ?  Doesn't **so** coordinate the two clauses, and cast the second clause as the rationale for the action in the first clause?  "Here's an extra sweater. It is so you don't catch cold this winter."

Comment: @TimR: I don't understand. The sentence *I bought him a phone so [that] I could call him* is semantically and syntactically identical regardless of whether optional ***that*** is included or not (the word ***that*** has no meaningful syntactic role here). It really is just a "noise word" in such contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I eliminated **that** in my example  because in your comment you treated **so that** as a unit. I wanted to focus on **so**.  I think we agree. You want to eliminate **that** as well.   But I think there's an argument that **so that** is becoming 'grammaticalized' or turned into a unit in its own right.

Comment: @TimR: Some RP speakers probably classify it as "uneducated / dialectal", but many people use ***so as*** (often contracted to ***so's***) instead of ***so that*** or plain ***so***. But I think [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did+it+so+I%2Cdid+it+so+that+I&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) strongly suggests that far from becoming "grammaticalized", the word ***that*** as a relativizer is fast heading into the dustbin of linguistic history!

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I haven't used **that** myself for years.  I was on the cusp, as they say.  I think **so as** is similar to **so that** but in standard English it takes a clause headed by a marked infinitive: "... so as to close the door automatically".  I've heard it also in non-standard use (so as, so's) : "I'm wearing this tinfoil on my head so as the aliens don't read my mind."

Comment: "so as the aliens don't read my mind" ... I would assume a non-native speaker if I heard this. Is it American? "so as to close the door" sounds ok. You need something after the "so".

Comment: [to be confused by something; or just to be confused//I appreciate takes the ing verb: I appreciate your giving me an answer; the verb to appreciate is not used like this: I'm appreciated in this context: I'm appreciated for who I am, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'So that' is a conjunction. It links the statement about action or intent to the purpose. In this example, and many cases, 'so' alone would suffice.

I would write your statement like this:

> I gave my dad a mobile phone last year **so that** I can contact him whenever I want to.

Your version is grammatically correct, but unnecessarily long. Because you end the statement about your action (giving you dad a phone) you then have to use the pronoun "this" when opening your new sentence to refer back to the thing you just said.

Comment: Thanks, your sentence is normal and formal.However,I am confusing because my reference books and my teachers told me that the clause of "so that" is Adverbial Clause which modify verbs. Would you explain this? I am appreciated to receive your reply.

Comment: @龚诗豪 As they commented above, "that" in "[so (that)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/so-that)" can be omitted, and "so" is a coordination conjunction that connects two separate sentences. To be precise,'so' is a transitional word.

Comment: @Mr. Wang   Thanks, the examples you provide is normal but my confusion of "this is so I can contact him" is whether "so that" or "so" is Noun clause or Adverbial Clause. As me commented above, my reference books and my teachers told me that the clause of "so that" is Adverbial Clause which modify verbs.

Comment: @龚诗豪 your teacher is wrong.

Comment: This doesn't explain the presence of "is" in the OP's second version, which is what the question is about. How can a linking verb like "is" have a conjunction and a clause after it? What does "is" link? What does the conjunction conjoin? How can those both be happening at the same time?

Answer (score -2):

I believe your confusion is how the linking verb "is" can link "*This*" with "*so that I can...*".

If the pronoun ["this"] referred simply to the entire previous sentence, rewritten with substitution it would mean:

> *[I gave my dad a mobile phone last year] is so that I can contact him whenever I want to.

Of course, this is bad grammar, so we know "this" means something else. In the context of "so that...", "this" means something like, "***the reason** I gave my dad a mobile phone last year*". Now the grammar is good, and it all makes sense:

> The reason I gave my dad a mobile phone last year is so that I can contact him whenever I want to.

Note that this isn't something special about "so" or "so that". It's the same with "to", and probably anything else that naturally comes after "*the reason...*":

> I gave my dad a phone. This is **to** be able to contact him whenever I want to.

Comment: I'm appreciated to have received your reply. As you commented above, the confusion is similar. My confusion is whether the conjunction of "so" or "so that" can only connect  Adverbial Clause which only modifies verbs because the linking verb "is" lack of complement.Personally, the sentence of "this is so" look strange

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you asking (1) if "so (that)" clauses are always adverbial clauses? Or (2) if these adverbial clauses only modify verbs? or (3) whether this happens because "is" lacks a complement?

Comment: I'm confusing the first question.

Comment: Ah. I'm not sure how "*so that...*" clauses are categorized.